# Transition effect in height of a div

Tags: html, css, hover, height, css-transitions

**My current situation:**

http://jsfiddle.net/VOXRAZR/2a6r4/2/

**My current problem:**
*Height of the div doesn't have transition effect and the outer div's height increases on hover (i dont want that!)*

**HTML**

```
<div id="black_bar"></div>
<div id="top_nav">
<a href="#"><div class="menu" id="home">HOME</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">LIST OF CAR MANUFACTURERS</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">WHY USE CARZPEDIA?</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">ABOUT US</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">CONTACT US</div></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
#top_nav{
    background-color:#000;
    height:auto;
}
#top_nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:1em;
    font-size:1em;
}
.menu:hover{
    background-color:#09F;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
    height:3em;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition:all 500ms ease;
    transition:all 500ms ease;
}
#home{
    color:#09F;
}
#home:hover{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a fixed height for the top bar (this is `#top_nav` in your CSS), and (optionally) set `overflow:hidden;` on it too (or the content will pop out when you hover over it. don't know if this is intentional)

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a6r4/3/) with overflow hidden

Or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2a6r4/4/) with overflow visible

Comment: I *think* OP also wanted the `.menu` divs to animate from their current height to their expanded height. To do that, you need to give them a fixed height in their non-expanded form, since you can't transition to/from `height: auto`.  [A fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/vwV7L/).

Comment: Hey that looks neat. 
+1. 
I'm having a hard time figuring out what OP means.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a reddit term and I wasn't thinking.  OP = original poster.

Comment: Lol miscommunication strikes again. I know what "OP" means, but i couldn't figure out what the OP (as a person) meant with his question :P

Comment: Ha. :) I think what he meant by "Height of the div doesn't have transition effect" is that he wanted the inner divs to transition to their hover height. Not 100% sure, though.

Comment: Thanks Ryan now there is only one problem since outer div have a fixed height it will not show other menu if the resolution is small like a mobile device check out this http://jsfiddle.net/VOXRAZR/vwV7L/1/

Comment: @VOXRAZR I think it's showing them, only it's white text on a white bg (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/NqHTC/)). But you're right that you'd probably need another solution on mobile. Personally, I think an accordion model works better on mobile menus than something like this, but you can experiment and see what works for you.